# how to click a div using selenium

Tags: javascript, html, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using ui-grid, i am trying to click the header of the grid to do sort.

According to the code of ui-grid, they seems just use

```html
<div class="sortable"/>
```

and use css  to make the div clickable

```css
.ui-grid-header-cell .sortable {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

I use selenium get the element of sortable, but calling click() directly seems not work for this.

Please advice how I can do click on the div?

Thanks!

Comment: Which selenium language bindings are you using?

Comment: Css doesn't make anything 'clickable'. Your example only changes the way the mouse cursor looks when you hover over it. You need some sort of click event handler on the div in order to make something happen on click().

Comment: @DonBottstein, you are right, I was looking at the wrong div.